# Delete forwarded mail, without deleting the original mail

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I use Google Apps Script to forward some important mails to my another mail-id. After forwarding mail, I want to delete the forwarded mail instead of deleting the original mail. I tried with:

```
         `messages[m].moveToTrash();`
```

but it deleted forwarded mail and original mail also. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Open the conversation.
Go to the forwarded message, not the original one.
Click on the pulldown menu next to "Reply".
Click on "Delete this message".

Comment: Manually deleting kind of defeats the purpose of doing it with a script.